# extjs 3.4 scrollbar disappears when panel collapses

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, scrollbar, extjs3

I am creating an EXT form that uses several `Panel` components, one of which collapses to the left. When it does so The `Panel` on the right (called centrePanel, because although it's on the right it has a region of 'center') and its children  expand. The immediate children of `centrePanel` are `Panel`s that have been set to scroll if the data on them cannot fit on the `Panel`. The problem I am experiencing is that when I collapse the `Panel` on the left, any scrollbars disappear. Expanding does not bring them back. However two things to note are:

- I can still scroll in both `Panel`s using my mouse.
- After the collapsible `Panel` has been collapsed and expanded once and any scrollbars disappear, when the left `Panel` is subsequently collapsed the scrollbar on the other panels briefly becomes visible again. Once the collapse event has finished the scrollbars are no longer visible. This does not happen when the `Panel` is expanded again.

Here is the relevant code.

Collapsible `Panel` (declared on the fly as part of the items of the window):

```
         region: "west",
         width: "38%",
         title: "Filter",
         collapsible: true,
         items: [myFilterFormPanel],
         listeners:{
          collapse: function(panel){
              //Make centre panel and children wider when filter panel is collapsed.
              centrePanel.setWidth(1000);
              searchResultsPanel.setWidth(1000);
              myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(0, 540);
              myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(1, 165);
              myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(2, 165);
                },
          expand: function(panel){
             //Make centre panel and children wider when filter panel is collapsed.
             centrePanel.setWidth(659);
             searchResultsPanel.setWidth(659);
             myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(0, 200);
             myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(1, 90);
             myColumnModel.setColumnWidth(2, 90);
      }
  }
```

myFilterFormPanel:

```
var myFilterFormPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    border: false,
    id: windowId + "myfilter",
    items: [stationsPanel, datesPanel, daysPanel, impactPanel, searchButton]
});
```

centrePanel (contains panels that are scrollable but is not scrollable itself):

```
var centrePanel = new Ext.Panel({
    border: false,
    items: [searchResultsPanel, individualResultPanel]
    }
});
```

searchResultsPanel (this becomes scrollable when necessary):

```
        var searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            title: "All Results",
            id: windowId + "allresults",
            region: "north",
            height: 250,
            border: false,
            padding: 10,
            autoScroll: true,
//            style:'overflow-y:auto',
            colModel: myColumnModel,
            store: myStore,
            listeners: {
                rowclick: function(thisRow, rowIndex){
                    //Display additional information in individual result panel.
                    var myData = myStore.getAt(rowIndex).data;
                    individualResultPanel.body.update("<h1><u>Summary</u></h1><p>" + myData.summary + "</p>"
                        + "<h1><u>Body</u></h1><p>" + myData.body + "</p>"
                        + "<h1><u>Additional Information</u></h1><p>" + myData.additionalInformation + "</p>"
                        + "<h1><u>Customer Information</u></h1><p>" + myData.customerInformation + "</p>"
                        + "<h1><u>Further Information</u></h1><p>" + myData.furtherInformation + "</p>"");
                }
            }
        });
```

individualResultPanel (also becomes scrollable);

```
var individualResultPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    border: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    title: "Selected Result",
    id: windowId + "individualresult",
    region: "south",
    height: 250,
    padding: 10,
});
```

In the `searchResultsPanel` I tried setting the style to be `overflow:auto;` which is what setting `autoScroll` to `true` does anyway but this didn't change anything. I also tried reducing the width of one of the srollable `Panel`s but this also made no difference. I thought about dynamically changing the style of the scrollable `Panel`s when the collapsible `Panel` is collapsed but given that I can always scroll, I don't think this will make a difference but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) so that we can play around with it a little. But otherwise.. Good post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem but by changing code that I did not supply in my original question. I had set `expand` and `collapse` listeners on the collapsible `Panel` so that when these events were fired, I was manually setting the widths of the `Panel` components (using hardcoded values) and, for the `GridPanel`, I was additionally setting the width of the columns within the `GridPanel`'s `ColumnModel`. Removing these lines of code allowed the scrollbars to remain when the collapsible `Panel` was collapsed and expanded.